# Drupal Can't access Drupal Admin Dashboard

Tags: php, linux, drupal-7, ubuntu

I tried many times installing drupal on kubuntu with xampp (including after reinstalling kubuntu) and can't access Drupal Admin Dashboard.

These are the commands after reinstalling kubuntu

go to :
/home/rebirth/Downloads: type: 
-sudo tar xvfz drupal-7.34.tar.gz
-mv drupal-7.34 ../../../opt/lampp/htdocs
-cd ../../../..
-sudo cp /opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal-7.34/sites/default/default.settings.php /opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal-7.34/sites/default/settings.php
-cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal-7.34/sites
-sudo chmod a+w default-sudo chmod a+w default/settings.php

Then I install drupal by typing the url localhost + : "/drupal-7.34/"

I install using root as a username and setting up a password, create the database etc..

When I finish the installation it shows drupal without the Drupal Admin Dashboard and I tried many times login in it doesn't work ...

Is there a file saving the password and username to be an administrator or do I Have to use the webbrowser as root?

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uncomment line 340 on settings.php to reflect your domain name

e.g. for localhost

```
$cookie_domain = 'localhost';
```

Please note this works for drupal 7 and my php version is 5.6. and ubuntu 14.10 you should also have rights to read and write the settings.php

Type your link

eg. `http://yourdomain/drupal/user/`

enter correct credentials you should be able to login

Regards,

Comment: It works! you work, funny answer came late. I'm extremely busy with career but I think I'll probably use drupal somewhere in the future. Better be safe.

Comment: This worked for me using `drupal 7.35` on `Windows 7`.